# distance between current position and black line opencv

Tags: python, opencv, robotics

[image]

Consider the image above, which serves as a map of the environment.
Each of the black lines indicate a "wall".

The problem is to make the simulated robot (of diameter 10 px) reach the bottom right yellow box using a series of `Forward`, `TurnRight` and `TurnLeft` actions. Forward moves the robot by 5 px; each turn action changes the robot orientation by 30 degrees.

- The positions of the walls are not fixed. But the size of the map is fixed `(200 px X 200 px)`.
- I start from any random location `(x, y)` and orientation (`theta = pi/2.0`) on the map.
- I track the `(x, y)` coordinates and the orientation (`theta`) as the robot moves.

Given the current location of the robot `(x, y)`, I need to find the distances to the nearest walls in all 4 directions.

How can I determine the distances using OpenCV functions?

(I am starting off with OpenCV/vision only now.)

Edit 1:

Here is what I tried:

(1) Get the "walls" alone:

```
for i in range(img.shape[0]):
    for j in range(img.shape[1]):
        if any(img[i,j] == 255):
            gs_black[i,j] = [255,255,255]
        else:
            gs_black[i,j] = [0,0,0]
```

This gives me:

[image]

(2) Get the pixel location of the walls

```
walls = []
for i in range(img.shape[0]):
    for j in range(img.shape[1]):
        if all(img[i,j] == 0):
            walls.append([i, j])
```

Edit 2:

Based on @Miki 's suggestion, tried to get the distance transform

```
thresh = cv2.threshold(gs_img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
from skimage.morphology import watershed
from scipy import ndimage
D = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(thresh)
```

Visualizing the transform gives:

[image]

Now, I am not sure what to make of this transform values.

Comment: Have a look at "Distance Transform"

Comment: @Miki I updated my question with what I tried based on your suggestion. However, I am unsure what to make out of it.

Comment: Also, some of the information about the walls is lost in the transform

Comment: You missed a few walls in the `threshold` function... please double check. Now you have for each point the distance to the closest wall. You can also know if you're going to hit the wall or not.

Comment: I think I did RGB2GRAY transform instead of BGR2RGB + RGB2GRAY or BGR2GRAY; I can see all the walls now